# How to compile and run Java Program with Sublime Text 2 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: java, sublimetext2, ubuntu-14.04

When i am trying to compile and run Java code with Sublime Text 2, i am getting the following error

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied
[cmd:  [u'build_java.sh', u'Ashru']]
[dir:  /home/ashrumochan/sublimeapps]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games]
[Finished]
```

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.
Please help how to solve this error.....

This is my build_java.sh file content

```
#!/bin/bash 
# compiles all java files within directory and runs first argument
for file in *.java
do
echo "Compiling $file"
javac $file
done
echo "Running $1"
java $1
```

Thsi is my JavaC.sublime-build content

```
{
   "cmd": ["build_java.sh", "$file_base_name"]
}
```

Comment: `javac NameOfClassFile.java` and `java NameOfClass` is the simplest way to compile...What does this `build_java.sh` executable do, and why does it require elevated privileges?  Conversely, are you sure that you have read, write, and execute privileges for that folder?

Comment: You probably just don't have the right to run this file. `chmod +x` this file and it should be alright. And to answer your question @Makoto, this script is probably the script that allows sublime text to compile and run java. In other words, probably a call to `javac` and such.

Comment: @Makoto,Now I have added my `build_java.sh` content and the `JavaC.sublime-build` content.Please check it.

Comment: `javac *.java` would be better as all imports will be resolved as you compile all of your source at one time

Comment: Thank you @Makoto and @Xælias for your response.Actually i didn't set the permission to my `build_java.sh` script before.But now i have set the permission and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the permissions on your script file so that it is executable. One way to do this is to run `chmod 755 build_java.sh` from the command-line.